# Unable to cancel the alarm from AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have an `AlarmManager` that notifies me every 10 seconds. Everything works just fine but for some reason I can't cancel the alarm. Here's my code.

```
public class AlarmNotifReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
//things
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pi); // Millisec * Second
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
}


}
```

as expected I call this `CancelAlarm()` method from my other classes but for some reason it does not cancel and keep notifying me like nothing happened.
Note: `SetAlarm()` also works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295604/how-to-set-an-alarm-in-android-java

Comment: oh sadly, that is not my problem, I am on my live brand mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alarm should be created and cancelled on Same Pending intent.In your case you are creating Pending Intent Twice.

Your code should look like below.

```
public class AlarmNotifReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    PendingIntent pi;
    AlarmManager am;
    Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
        //things
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context) {

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10 * 1000, pi);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
        am.cancel(pi);
    }


}
```

Comment: This makes the receiver unable to start with a NullPointerException

Comment: okay, after struggling a little found out that initializing the PendingIntent twice was the problem, thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try to cancel Pendingintent--

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 
                           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[Android: Get all PendingIntents set with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315611/android-get-all-pendingintents-set-with-alarmmanager)

To cancel all alarm, first you have to find all the pending intent for that and cancel alarm using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public class AlarmNotifReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

AlarmManager am = null;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
//things
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pi); // Millisec * Second
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {

am.cancel(pi);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're creating a NEW intent instead of cancelling the existing one. Function SetAlarm should place the intent into a "global" variable and the CancelAlarm function should just call
    am.cancel(global_pi);

The above worked for me in a service, but:

If this is impossible (since that's a Receiver), try setting a new alarm with the (new) intent first.

Comment: As long as you're putting `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag, then it knows to match and cancel / update.